# The usage of _InterlockedCompareExchange64

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

On MSDN, I see that

```
InterlockedCompareExchange64
```

requires parameters to be 64 aligned,

but for

```
_InterlockedCompareExchange64
```

I see no such requirement for alignment, and it is 
mentioned to provide  compiler intrinsic support for the  InterlockedCompareExchange64.

So, does this means I can use _InterlockedCompareExchange64 without caring about alignment? 'Cause I don't quite know what alignment means here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that is a documentation mistake, rather than any direct difference between the two function - seeing as they result in exactly the same CMPXCHG8B instruction. [Assuming of course you are looking for it it to actually be atomic on an SMP system - but it's a pretty specialized instruction, so I doubt it has much other use].

Comment: Thanks Mats, so does this means I have to use _aligned_malloc to allocate addresses for the three parameters of this function?

Comment: It means that you have to ensure that the values are aligned on a 64-bit boundary. That doesn't necessarily mean that they have to be individually allocated. Typically, the compiler will align 64-bit values on a 64-bit boundary anyway, so you shouldn't have a problem unless you are using two `int` instead of one `long long`, or if you have been playing around with `#pragma pack()` etc.

Comment: Ah, yes, using 64-bit on a 64 machine solves this. Thank you very much, you helped to understand this.

Answer (score 4):

It is implied, the _underscore version is only available when _M_IA64 or _M_AMD64 is defined.  In other words, when you target your program to a 64-bit processor.

You should use the non-underscore version in your code.  When you target a 32-bit processor then the function is implemented in Windows and you'll get a safe version that works with a misaligned destination.  But if you target a 64-bit processor then you'll automatically get the _underscore version and the intrinsic.  Macro soup in WinBase.h takes care of it.